# Unknown engine type outputformat

Tags: 7, drush, aegir

Hello I've just updated Drupal (to version 7.53) and now in Drush when I try launch the commands:
"drush @theflyingeye.org up" (to update my website)
or
"drush @theflyingeye.org cc" (to clean chache)
or
"drush @theflyingeye.org dl view" (to download a basic module, view for example)
I can just get this answer:
"Unknown engine type outputformat"

If I digit:

```
"drush status" (after "su aegir")
I can get: 
"PHP configuration     :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini                                 
 Drush version         :  5.10.0                                                
 Drush configuration   :  /var/aegir/.drush/drushrc.php                         
 Drush alias files     :  /var/aegir/.drush/server_master.alias.drushrc.php     
                          /var/aegir/.drush/theflyingeye.org.alias.drushrc.php  
                          /var/aegir/.drush/server_localhost.alias.drushrc.php
```

Do you have any advise please to fix this problem?

Comment: Try clearing the drush cache. drush cc drush

Comment: Also upgrading to Drush 8 could help ... see http://www.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: Drush 5.10 is ancient so you should really, really upgrade. What does  ```drush --debug version``` report? The "Unknown engine type outputformat" error indicates that you have another Drush around ...

Comment: Sort of looks like you have a contrib module that has a Drush extension that is using a feature not available in Drush 5.10. Try upgrading as suggested by others.

Comment: Hansfn, if I "drush --debug version" i get: Bootstrap to phase 0. [0 sec, 3.81 MB] Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0 sec, 4.03 MB] Loading drushrc "/var/aegir/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush"    [bootstrap]
scope. [0.02 sec, 4.04 MB] Cache HIT cid: 5.10.0-commandfiles-0-5ddf65b044b60bcd12160894847f471e    [debug]
[0.06 sec, 4.06 MB] Loading apache driver for the http service [0.27 sec, 10.77 MB]         [notice]
drush version 5.10.0 *** and some details ***

Answer (score 0):

Start with upgrading to Drush 8 ... see http://drush.org/en/master/install

Comment: Thank you. I would like to specify the original installation is with AEGIR. Do you know if there is any special trick to update Drush through Aegir ?

Comment: The 'manual' upgrade script does it like [this](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/provision/tree/upgrade.sh.txt#n177) pretty much like the Drush docs suggest it.